# Are reactive extensions suitable only for API calls that return collection?

Tags: rx-java, system.reactive, reactive-programming, rx.net

I have a proxy that calls multiple REST APIs to create a course grained output for the UI. The UI is built with KnockoutJS. I am using tasks/ async methods to call the APIs asynchronously. Only 1 or 2 of the APIs return a list, all others return flat value objects. Can Rx be used for combining the results of those APIs that do not return a collection? Since the output is not a collection it means it is not an event stream so does combining such api calls with Rx be against the Rx guidelines?

Comment: Can you please share some code ?

Comment: In both cases you are returning a single value (in the Rx sense of the world). That single item may be a scalar value or a collection, but it is still just a single HTTP response (making the assumption here that when you say REST you mean HTTP). If you response was a stream of messages from a WebSocket or an Atom feed then yes in the Rx terms you would then have a sequence of events with a cardinality of more than 1. Either way, Rx will happily deal with sequences of 0, 1 or many.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Since the output is not a collection it means it is not an event stream so does combining such api calls with Rx be against the Rx guidelines?

See an API call as a Stream of only one event. This event can be a `List`, or just an `Object`.

> Can Rx be used for combining the results of those APIs that do not return a collection?

Yes! Reactive Extentions is an API for asynchronous calls. It doesn't matter if your API returns a collection, an object, or nothing.

example :

```
  interface YourRemoteApi {
         Observable<List<String>> users();
         Observable<User> userData(String id);
         Observable<Void> deleteUser(String id);
  }


  class Main {

          public static void main(String...args) {

               YourRemoteApi api = ...
               api.users()
                  // transform an Observable<List<String>> to Observable<String>
                  .flatMapIterable(ids -> ids)
                  // call in a async fashion api.userData()
                  .contatMap(id -> api.userData(id))
                  .filter(data -> data.toDelete())
                  // call in a async fashion api.deleteUser
                  .flatMap(data -> api.deleteUser(data.id))
                  .subscribe();
          }

  }
```

PS : This example uses RxJava. It may differ in another language port (such as Reactive Extensions for .NET, etc.)

Comment: Just because you can does not mean that you should. In Java, you have incredibly limited expressiveness and no syntactic support for asynchronous programming. In C#, VB, and practically any other language, you have far more sophisticated options. Java is terrible - do not see the world in terms of it.